# Node.js and node_redis - Parsing HGETALL response to Jade template (Object with Buffers)

Tags: json, node.js, pug, node-redis

I am using the node_redis NPM module (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and the docs state that "HGETALL returns an Object with Buffers keyed by the hash keys."

If i log the output to a console, I get something like:

```
{ 'foo': '{"data":{},"config":{}}',
  'bar': '{"data":{},"config":{}}',
  'baz': '{"data":{},"config":{}}' }
```

NOTE the single quotes wrapping each child key.

When I parse this to a Jade template, I can access access `foo`, `bar` and `baz` with:

```
-for(var prop in all)
  li #{prop}
  li #{all[prop]}
```

I cannot access any of the child key values e.g. data or config. I would expect to be able to access these with `all[prop].data`. Im guessing this is because of the strange format of the JSON. I have no idea what "Object with Buffers keyed by the hash keys" means so do not know how to process the output from node_redis.

Can anyone advise how I can access the child key values? Im guessing the format needs to be solved first.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who encounters this issue, I solved it by parsing the child item:

```
-for(var prop in all)
  #{prop}
    -var ob = JSON.parse(all[prop])
```

Now ob properties can be accessed using dot notation.